# Run-time error number 5 ("Invalid procedure call or argument") when trying to return LocationURL

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I'm trying to store the `LocationURL`property of an Internet explorer object but I'm getting a

> Run-time error 5 ("Invalid procedure call or argument")

when doing so and can't figure out what the issue is - Here's my code:

```
Sub MyMacro()
Dim IE As Object
Dim URL As String

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With sh.Windows(0)
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "www.google.com"
End With

Do
    DoEvents
Loop While IE Is Nothing
Do
    DoEvents
Loop While IE.ReadyState <> 4
Do
    DoEvents
Loop While IE.Document.ReadyState <> "complete"

URL = IE.LocationURL 'Here's where it crashes 

End Sub
```

If I enter "?IE.LocationURL" in the immediate window and enter, it'll give me the "https://www.google.ie/" that I would expect so I can't see why this can't be assigned to a sting and can't find enough on the error itself to figure it. There's also nothing online that I've been able to find... Can someone advise what I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: what is the `sh` ?  ... why are you using `sh.Windows(0)` object instead of the `IE` object?

Comment: @Jeremy ,someone is trying to fix your issues and you on the other hand don't care to respond whether the suggested code is working or not.

Comment: @Shahin That's not the case - I haven't been able to check-in on this because of work commitments - I've figured out my problem in the meantime in any event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyMacro()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim URL As String

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "www.google.com"

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.busy

    URL = IE.LocationURL 'Here's where it crashes
    Debug.Print URL

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I've figured out my problem (I feel kinda stupid now but anyways! Thanks again